# JavaFX TreeTableView doesn't update column on repeated expand

Tags: java, javafx, treetableview

I have a `TreeTableView` with two columns. The first column shows a label and the second column shows an action text with a custom `CellFactory`.

The first time I expand the node, the action text is set correctly. But when I repeat to expand the Node, the action text doesn't update.

The screenshots demonstrate the not expected behavior:
[application start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTWJj.png), [first expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nb5N.png), [second expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aKDx.png)

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    
    public class MainApp extends Application {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(MainApp.class, args);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    
            final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> root = buildTree();
    
            // Creating columns
            TreeTableColumn<LabeldTreeItem, String> labelColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("label");
            TreeTableColumn<LabeldTreeItem, String> actionColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("action");
    
            labelColumn.setMinWidth(120);
            actionColumn.setMinWidth(120);
    
            // Defining cell content
            labelColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("label"));
    
            // cell factory to display action text **click me!**
            actionColumn.setCellFactory(ttc -> new TreeTableCell<LabeldTreeItem, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String value, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(value, empty);
    
                    final LabeldTreeItem item = this.getTreeTableRow().getItem();
    
                    this.setText(null);
                    this.setGraphic(null);
    
                    if (empty) {
                        this.setText("empty");
                    } else if (item == null) {
                        this.setText("null item");
                    } else if (item.isClickMe()) {
                        this.setText("click me!");
                    }
                }
            });
    
            //Creating a tree table view
            final TreeTableView<LabeldTreeItem> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(root);
            treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(List.of(labelColumn, actionColumn));
            treeTableView.setShowRoot(false);
    
            stackPane.getChildren().add(treeTableView);
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane, 300, 250));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    
        public class LabeldTreeItem {
            private final String label;
            private final boolean clickMe;
    
            public LabeldTreeItem(String label, boolean clickMe) {
                this.label = label;
                this.clickMe = clickMe;
            }
    
            public String getLabel() {
                return label;
            }
    
            public boolean isClickMe() {
                return clickMe;
            }
        }
    
        private TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> buildTree() {
            final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> root = new TreeItem<>();
            root.setExpanded(true);
    
            final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> node = new TreeItem<>(new LabeldTreeItem("Node", false));
            final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> item1 = new TreeItem<>(new LabeldTreeItem("Item 1", true));
            final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> item2 = new TreeItem<>(new LabeldTreeItem("Item 2", false));
            final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> item3 = new TreeItem<>(new LabeldTreeItem("Item 3", true));
    
            node.getChildren().addAll(List.of(item1, item2, item3));
            root.getChildren().add(node);
    
            return root;
        }    
    }
```

I have tried these with Java 11 and JavafX 16.

Comment: why don't you have a valueFactory on the second column? you need some trigger that the cell is updated ..

Comment: hi @kleopatra, thank you for your suggestion. The code is just an example and the goal of the second column should contain many Buttons with different possible action, that could be triggered.

Comment: (at least) if the cell content changes on some condition, a valueFactory is _mandatory_ (otherwise it's not updated which is what you see). F.i. let it return an observable that's bound to the treeItem's expanded, value, property of value as needed.

Comment: Thank you @kleopatra for the inspiring comments. I was able to solve the problem myself. Finally, a valueFactory must be set. In my case it was the "clickMe" property. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Solution works for me. I have to set a valueFactory for the second column.
In these case I use my existing "cklickMe" property.

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(MainApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

        final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> root = buildTree();

        //Creating columns
        TreeTableColumn<LabeldTreeItem, String> labelColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("label");
        TreeTableColumn<LabeldTreeItem, Boolean> actionColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("action");

        labelColumn.setMinWidth(120);
        actionColumn.setMinWidth(120);

        // Defining cell content
        labelColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("label"));
        // ** must be set **
        actionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("clickMe"));

        // cell factory to display button:
        actionColumn.setCellFactory(ttc -> new TreeTableCell<LabeldTreeItem, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Boolean value, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(value, empty);

                final LabeldTreeItem item = this.getTreeTableRow().getItem();

                this.setText(null);
                this.setGraphic(null);

                if (empty) {
                    this.setText("empty");
                } else if (item == null) {
                    this.setText("null item");
                } else if (item.isClickMe()) {
                    this.setText("click me!");
                }
            }
        });

        //Creating a tree table view
        final TreeTableView<LabeldTreeItem> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(root);
        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(List.of(labelColumn, actionColumn));
        treeTableView.setShowRoot(false);

        stackPane.getChildren().add(treeTableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class LabeldTreeItem {
        private final String label;
        private final Boolean clickMe;

        public LabeldTreeItem(String label, Boolean clickMe) {
            this.label = label;
            this.clickMe = clickMe;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public boolean isClickMe() {
            return clickMe;
        }
    }

    private TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> buildTree() {
        final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> root = new TreeItem<>();
        root.setExpanded(true);

        final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> node = new TreeItem<>(new LabeldTreeItem("Node", false));
        final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> item1 = new TreeItem<>(new LabeldTreeItem("Item 1", true));
        final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> item2 = new TreeItem<>(new LabeldTreeItem("Item 2", false));
        final TreeItem<LabeldTreeItem> item3 = new TreeItem<>(new LabeldTreeItem("Item 3", true));

        node.getChildren().addAll(List.of(item1, item2, item3));
        root.getChildren().add(node);

        return root;
    }

}
```